# OrderBy Filter for Zulu time not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter the time `latest` to `null` in the below `HTML`. The time format is in Zulu(UTC) format i.e. `'2017/04/01T00:00:00.000Z'`.

```
<li ng-repeat="contact in $ctrl.contacts | orderBy: 'LastChatTime' | filter : searchContact track by $index">
```

When I do this. In records where time exists are sorted in reverse order and then null records are coming. 
e.g.:

```
 1. '2017/03/31T13:00:00.000Z'  
 2. '2017/04/01T00:00:00.000Z'  
 3. `Null`
```

Instead of :

```
 1. '2017/04/01T00:00:00.000Z' 
 2. '2017/03/31T13:00:00.000Z' 
 3. `Null`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice your records are arranged in ascending order, which is behavior of `orderBy`.

Here you need sort your `contacts` in descending order.

You can try below code,

```
<li ng-repeat="contact in $ctrl.contacts | orderBy: '-LastChatTime' | filter : searchContact track by $index">
```

`-` before `LastChatTime` will sort your contacts by descending order

**Note: This will not consider null values**

To support nulls while sorting you can try below

```
<li ng-repeat="contact in $ctrl.contacts | orderBy: '[!LastChatTime, -LastChatTime]' | filter : searchContact track by $index">
```